# CheckBox how to have to selected checkboxes

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have 5 checkboxes and I want the user to be able to select two at the same time, one is selected as default. I am able to select two chceck boxes, but then user must uncheck one check box in order to select a different.

This is the code I have

```
 int Sum = 0;
        int MaxCount = 1;
        private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, IsCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var box = sender as Checkbox;
            if (e.IsChecked  == true)
            {
                Sum++;
                if (Sum > MaxCount)
                {
                    box.IsChecked = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Sum--;
            }
        }
```

How would i achieve that?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  The only obvious issue I see is that you should decrement sum when you set `box.IsChecked = false;`

Comment: for example if user select check box 1 and checkbox two if he then decides to select check box 3 one of the two previous check boxes should uncheck automatically

Comment: personally, that sounds like bad UX to me.  I think what you have is a better approach, where you just don't allow them to check more than 2.  I would add some sort of error message explaining that to them

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
int Sum = 1;// if one is selected as default,the Sum = 1,if no selected,Sum = 0
int MaxCount = 2; //Maximum number which you could select
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = sender as CheckBox;
        if (box.IsChecked)
        {
            Sum++;
            if(Sum > MaxCount)
            {
                box.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Sum--;
        }


    }
```